# youtube-dl: Downloading a video as a best quality mp4 without audio?

Tags: video, youtube, mp4, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download videos from Youtube as their best quality mp4, without the audio.

I know I can use youtube-dl -F to see all available formats, choose one and then run another command, but I want to download videos automatically through a script. The furthest I've got is:

```
youtube-dl -f mp4 <URL>
```

But this chooses the best mp4 option which has audio also, and so usually isn't the best video quality (720p instead of 1080p).

Does anyone know how to do this? Please let me know! :)

Comment: You might be able to get more help for this on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/youtube-dl).  From the [youtube-dl tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/youtube-dl/info): *Note that questions about installing and using youtube-dl are off-topic for Stack Overflow. They may be more appropriate on SuperUser.*

Answer (score 1):

It seems like using bestvideo and then specifying the output path with an mp4 extension works:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo -o "%(title)s.mp4" <URL>
```

Looking at the download options with -F, it seems like it still downloads the best video (regardless of it being an mp4 or not, in my case a webm), and then converts it to mp4? As the file sizes match between the downloaded file and the best quality in -F.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to get the best quality mp4 files that will play on a RPi, which is terrible for playing video in a browser:

```
youtube-dl --download-archive already.downloaded.txt -i -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best' [yootoobURL]
```

This also keeps a nice list of all the videos I've already downloaded. ;-)

You could exclude the “bestaudio” part and you’ll get exactly what you asked for.